# Oracle SQL - One to many - Join based on multiple unique conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables(table1 and table2). 'id' in table2 is a fk(from table 1). table2 describes the table1 and for the same 'id' from table1, table2 has multiple records. Please note that table2 can have other 'categories' as well(other than just 'veg' and 'non-veg').

```
table1
---------------------
id    amount     purchase_date
1     100        1/1/22
2     200        2/1/22
3     300        3/2/21
---------------------------

table2
---------------------------------
id    amount     category      desc
1     100        veg           abc
1     100        veg           xyz
1     100        non-veg       def
1     100        non-veg       jkl
2     300        veg           abc
2     300        veg           xyz
2     300        non-veg       def
2     300        non-veg       jkl
2     300        hot-veg       bvn
2     300        mad-veg       lji
-----------------------------------------
```

The result I want : For each id, one record for 'veg' and one for 'non-veg'. The desc column doesnt matter much to me(any one is fine in the result)

```
------------------------
id    amount    category
1     100       veg
1     100       non-veg
2     300       veg
2     300       non-veg
-----------------------
```

Am trying to join like below but it doesn't work
its giving me multiple records for each of the ids.

```
select * from 
table1 t1
inner join t2 on
t1.id = t2.id and t2.category in ('veg','non-veg')
```

Comment: you can do SELECT DISTINCT  T2.id   , T2.amount  ,   T2.category

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DISTINCT`:

```
with table1 as
(
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 100 AS amount, TO_DATE('01/01/22','DD/MM/YYYY')  AS purchase_date FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 200, TO_DATE('02/01/22','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 300, TO_DATE('03/02/21','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL
),
table2 as
(
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 100 AS amount, 'veg' AS CATEGORY  , 'abc' AS DEC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 100, 'veg'    , 'xyz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 100, 'non-veg', 'def' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 100, 'non-veg', 'jkl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 300, 'veg'    , 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 300, 'veg'    , 'xyz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 300, 'non-veg', 'def' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 300, 'non-veg', 'jkl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 300, 'hot-veg', 'bvn' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 300, 'mad-veg', 'lji' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT DISTINCT T2.id , T2.amount , T2.category
  FROM table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.category IN ('veg','non-veg');
```